# Using decorator yields NameError on a defined function

Tags: python, python-decorators

Why does this :

```
def fn(proc, *args, **kwargs):
    cache = proc.cache = {}
    def cached_execution(cache, *args, **kwargs):
        if proc in cache:
            if args in cache[proc]:
                return cache[proc][args]
        res = proc(args)
        cache[proc] = {args: res}
        return res
    return cached_execution(cache, proc, *args, **kwargs)

@fn
def cached_fibo(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return cached_fibo(n-1) + cached_fibo(n-2)

print cached_fibo(100)
```

throw an exception like this:

> NameError: global name 'cached_fibo' is not defined

What fundamental concept am I missing?

(Conceptually, `**kwargs` is for decoration only. Not utilizing in retrieving the cached result, but don't worry about it).

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decorator should return a function, not the result of calling a function. 
But this leads us to the next mistake: when you're passing `cache` and `proc` to `cached_execution` function they land in `*args` which in turn gets passed to `proc`. This doesn't make sense. Just let `cache` and `proc` be captured within the inner method:

```
def fn(proc, *args, **kwargs):
    cache = proc.cache = {}
    def cached_execution(*args, **kwargs):
        if proc in cache:
            if args in cache[proc]:
                return cache[proc][args]
        res = proc(*args)
        cache[proc] = {args: res}
        return res
    return cached_execution
```

Another problem: you were not unpacking `args`. You should call `proc(*args)` instead of `proc(args)` (already fixed above).

Comment: my bad my bad. I was returning the function call instead of function. silly mistakes. but thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Note that this still doesn't actually work.  It'll run, I mean, but since it blows away the process cache each time (`cache[proc] = {args: res}`), you don't get any of the benefits of memoization.  You should use something like `cache.setdefault(proc, {})[args] = res`.

Comment: yes didnt fix that. i was deeply concerned with the first issue. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user2290820 Please don't add answers to the question post. You can post your own answer instead if you want to share the outcome (which is great of course! :) ). I've removed it, but you can find it in question's edit history.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper seems a little malformed. Here is an updated version:

```
def fn(proc):
    cache = proc.cache = {}

    def cached_execution(*args, **kwargs):
        if proc in cache:
            if args in cache[proc]:
                return cache[proc][args]
        res = proc(args[0])
        cache[proc] = {args: res}
        return res
    return cached_execution
```

You were trying to run the wrapper function inside the wrapper instead of returning it to be run as the function, causing issues.

The next issue is that the argument you supply is a list of tuples `*args` at `proc(args)` when you only want the first one, so needs to turn into `proc(args[0])`

Comment: i need to wrap my head around the wrapper function inside the wrapper !